# ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundling and Minification: wrong paths in Debug Mode with Url Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I want to use the [ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) feature, please assume that we run the debug mode so nothing is bundled, but each reference is simply rendered to single tags. Locally everything works fine:

**Example**

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
 {
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
 }
```

When calling `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` from the view now, a tag similar to this is generated:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

The result **is the same** if I would just write:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
```

But when I deploy everything to a test server in the internet (still using the debug mode), there is some **Url rewriting** enabled, where I route specific domains or subdomains to specific folders.

For example, if the domain is `sub1.example.com` then forward to `example.com/__sub1__` and in case of `sub2.example.com` forward to `example.com/__sub2__` and so on. When I open `sub1.example.com` in the browser, there is usually no clue that this forward happens, the Url doesn't change, all Urls remain working and so do references generated using the `Url.Content(...)` method.

But for some strange reason, the call to `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` now renders something like this:

```
 <script src="/__sub1__/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Please note the "/**sub1**" part which is the part which shouldn't be generated and never appear somewhere in the rendered html code and leads to a 404 because the url rewrite forward fails.

While...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
```

...still renders the correct relative Path to "/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js". And i never had other problems with rewriting the Urls like this. And I don't want to get rid of this rewriting.

Obviously, the same applies to style sheets.

Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the current implementation of the script/style helpers, this should be fixed with the 1.1-alpha1 release that should be available shortly(early Oct) as the support for using the VirtualPathProvider registered with ASP.NET has fixed this general class of issue (resolving resource paths correctly).

Comment: It's great to get a reply from someone who's so deeply involved in, I'm sure that thats the most accurate answer I could get, thank you! I will accept this as the correct answer when I'm be able to verify this ;-)